# How to add the count of observations represented to each hexagon in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a heatmap using hexagons in the stat_summary_hex function. Everything is how I would like it to be. However, I want to fill each hexagon with count. So, I want it to show how many observations are housed in each hexagon.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 diamond <- diamonds

 p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = depth, y = carat, z = price)) +
 stat_summary_hex(fun = mean, bins = 8) +
 scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", midpoint = 
 3500)

 p
```

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Add a second `geom_summary_hex()` with `geom = "text"` and `fun = length`:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = depth, y = carat, z = price)) +
  stat_summary_hex(fun = mean, bins = 8) +
  stat_summary_hex(geom = "text", aes(label = after_stat(value)), fun = length, bins = 8) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", midpoint = 3500)
```

[image]